# Jquery dialog effect, stop animation queue

Tags: jquery, dialog, slide

I have added slide functionality on hover and on mouseout i close the dialog ( slide). If i repeatedly keep hovering and move the mouse pointer the slide works very slowly and the dialog keeps sliding. Any idea how to prevent that??

Also if i add "Modal:True" to the below code. The whole thing doesnt even work. Any solutions??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.image').each(function() {
            var panel = $(this).siblings('.descPanel');
            $(this).mouseover(function() {
                panel.dialog('open');
            });

            $(this).mouseout(function() {
                panel.dialog('close');
            });
        });

        $(".descPanel").dialog({ autoOpen: false,show:slide,hide:slide,
            open: function() {
                $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        });

</script>
```

HTML Strcuture:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr id="tr">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Jquery/Untitled.jpg" CssClass="image" />
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="mypanel" CssClass="descPanel">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="mylabel" CssClass="label" Text="hello"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr id="tr">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Jquery/Untitled.jpg" CssClass="image" />
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" CssClass="descPanel">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" CssClass="label" Text="hello1111"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: It's the Jquery Dialog which i am using here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `close` to `destroy`:

```
 $(this).mouseout(function() {
    panel.dialog('destroy');
 });
```